# I am using cordova map plugin in my ionic app.What is the event for android device like we have MAP_WILL_MOVE(iOS) for ios?

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework

I am newbie in ionic app development and I am on way to develop a location based app. The problem is with map plugin Cordova. In iOS when i scroll the map to get the center location an event gets triggered MAP_WILL_MOVE(iOS) which gives me the center lat long and its not working in android device because obvious its for iOS. What is the similar event which can be used to get the lat long in android device.
What I have tried till now is:
map.addEventListener(plugin.google.maps.event.MAP_WILL_MOVE, onMapMovement);
Its working great with iOS device but its not working with android device. Appreciate your help.
Thanks in advance

Comment: anyone who has faced this issue.....plz help me in this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In android, we have different method. I found one. Please follow this link to get some more events when you use google maps.
https://github.com/mapsplugin/cordova-plugin-googlemaps/wiki/Events